# How to deactivate a button in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity

We have a set of buttons in our game. Each one corresponds to a particular instrument. we have to implement the foll:

a button should become deactivated after being clicked once implying that the same instrument should not be taken twice.

how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Gamedev.SE! What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

This will hide the "button" completely from your scene until you decide otherwise.

I recommend you go through the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) so you can figure out these answers by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Unity superior or equal to 4.6, you can use [UI/Selectable-interactable](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html).

The button will cannot be used if *interactable* is set to false.

For example:

```
public Button instrumentButton;

void Update ()
{
    if (canPlayInstrument == false)) {
        instrumentButton.interactable = false;
    }
}
```